# Javascript being printed instead of ASP (classic) output

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm trying to make a page that lists records, and allows to show a form to edit a value. It reloads the page with "?edit=true" added to the end so it knows to pull the data into a form, rather than list all entries. I did this after loading it in an iframe to replace the body wasn't working. And I have managed to do this in a different form exactly the same way - except it worked. (Actually, I have two functions that show a form, and only 1 will show up)

The output I get instead of the form is

> ; }catch(e) { alert(e); }

This is at the bottom to be loaded last:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {

        document.getElementById("viewb").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("reviewb").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("editb").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("reeditb").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("delb").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML = "<%call showAScreen()%>";

        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    </script>
```

This is the first defined asp function - placed after the JavaScript functions at the top:

```
<% sub showAScreen()

If Request.QueryString("edit") <> "" Then
    showedits()
else
    showControlScreen()
end if 
end sub %>
```

This is the rest:

```
<% sub showedits() 'Show edit record form

        dim selsql
        selsql = ""
        selsql = selsql & "SELECT A.[NBK] as 'NBK ID'"
        selsql = selsql & " ,A.[PersonNumber] as 'Person Number'"
        ...
        selsql = selsql & " ,A.[AOIScore] as 'AOI Score'"
        selsql = selsql & " ,A.[VendorName] as 'Vendor Name'"
        selsql = selsql & "   FROM (([ReportingDevDB].[dbo].[bAssociateRoster] as A left join "
        selsql = selsql & "[ReportingDevDB].[dbo].[bAssociateRoster] as B on A.ManagerNBK = B.NBK) left join"
        selsql = selsql & "[ReportingDevDB].[dbo].[bAssociateRoster] as C on A.TeamLeadNBK = C.NBK)"
        selsql = selsql & " where A.NBK='" & Request.QueryString("edit") & "'"

        on error resume next
        set rs = cnt.execute(selsql)
        dim outstr
        outstr = "<table><tr><td id='content'>"'Frame for code to be pulled from.
        outstr = outstr & "<form id='form' method='post' action='NewRosterManager.asp?selectnbk=" & rs(0) & "&update=true'>"

            outstr = outstr & "<table class='bluetable'>"
            outstr = outstr & "<thead><tr><td colspan='32'>Edit Data</td></tr></thead>"
            outstr = outstr & "<tbody class='list' style='text-align:left'>"
            outstr = outstr & "<tr><td>NBK:</td><td id='RecordNBK'>" & rs(0) & "</td></tr>"
            ...
            outstr = outstr & "<tr><td>Vendor Name:</td><td><input type='text' id='e_VendorName' name='e_VendorName' value='" & rs(25) & "'></td></tr>"
            outstr = outstr & "</tbody></table><input type='submit'></form>"

        outstr = outstr & "</td></tr></table>"'Frame for code to be pulled from.
        Response.write "<br/>" & outstr & "<br/>"

        Response.write selsql 'this doesn't work... can't test query
end sub %>
```

Again... I have tried everything I can think of over the past week, and I cannot find anything remotely like this in my google searches. I cannot even get the query to print.

Comment: Have you tried checking the data being output? It might have "illegal" chars in it.. ie something that could cause the html to be invalid (eg. ', "). Try making some mock data, which you know is correct and output that.

Comment: Please also search for "SQL Injection Attack".  What happens if a user where to construct a URL that contains "edit='; DELETE ReportingDEVDB.dbo.bAssociateRoster; --" ?  Always use parameterised queries.

Comment: Moved the code to it's own page upon Holger's suggestion. It works there. Just not in the page it belongs.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones I have not gotten that far just yet, and the page is intranet anyways. I think replacing ' with '' works.. but I can't find enough proof. I've been denying anything that has sql keywords in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generated  should be in quotes, like this:

```
document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML = "<%call showAScreen()%>";
```

Notice the quotes around <% and %> tags.

ASP will call showAScreen and insert it inside javascript's quotes, so that the output will look like this:

```
document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML = "&lt;table&gt;...&lt;/table&gt;";
```

Update: in showAScreen, do this:

```
return "<br/>" & outstr & "<br/>"
```

and then

```
Response.write "document.getElementById('panel').innerHTML = """ & showAScreen() & """"
```

Comment: One of the changes I made yesterday was checking if removing them worked. I put them back... It's still not working.

Comment: Separate code, let showAScreen return a string and then output that string.

Comment: If the code posted is actual code, then try this: return string from showAScreen and then 
    Response.write "document.getElementById('panel').innerHTML = showAScreen()

Comment: Changed showedits() to a function and did that. It works! Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. I found myself in similar situation countless of times and one golden rule I found is, when the concerns are separated, it's easier to notice a problem. Good luck!